# Applying a mock bottom-border to a rotated div

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm currently using the CSS3 `rotate` value to give the appearance of an arrowhead for modal boxes. I'm now in a situation where I need to create an full arrowhead with a bottom border. Since this is just a div that's rotated at a 45° angle, applying another `border` to either of the two sides wouldn't solve the problem.

My first thought was to apply some styling the div's `:after` pseudo selector and vertically center it. For some reason though it's inheriting the rotate value. I've tried setting the value to `none` and tried to manually adjusting the rotation angle but to no avail. Any idea on how to get this border to reset  horizontally straight?

Through Harry's suggestion I set the angle of the `:after` selector to `-45deg` and `top` value to `50%`. The only problem now is that it doesn't fully expand to the left and right of the div. Any ideas?

```css
.arrow {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-top: 2px solid #c7c7c7;
  border-left: 2px solid #c7c7c7;
  position: relative;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;

  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  background: #c7c7c7;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

Comment: Children will always inherit parent's transform. You have to reverse the transform on child instead of `none` (that is, `rotate(-45deg)` to make it straight).

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/f8k7b4xj/) what you mean, or what you **don't** mean? Seeing your edit, this is clearly not what you were after. o_O

Comment: @Harry That straightened it out but now it seems that it's not expanding fully to the left and right of the div. I've updated my code example for you to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: For width, you'd have to use Pythagoras theorem. Use `width: calc(100% * 1.414)` (square root of 2). Because you are rotating the parent to form a triangle, the width would have to be equal to hypotenuse of the triangle which is nothing but sqrt(18^2 + 18^2). (Overall `top: calc(50% - 1px); left: -4px; height: 2px; width: calc(100% * 1.414);` should help you completely fit it).

Comment: I think that will make it expand appropriately but the left alignment is off. Is there any way to dynamically left-align the border without nudging and guessing what it should be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Using CSS Transforms:**

You can create a full arrowhead with bottom border using the approach adopted in the below snippet. Here, the arrowhead is created by the `:after` element while the line at the bottom is created using the parent container. The rotation axis is fixed using the same `transform-origin` for parent & child.

The shape created using this approach should be able to adapt itself to all dimensions without needing any tweaks to the positioning (hover the arrow in snippet to see it in action).

```css
.arrow {
  position: relative;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #c7c7c7;
}
.arrow:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: -1px;  /* half of border top */
  left: -2px;  /* equal to border left */
  height: calc(100% / 1.414); /* division by 1.414 because parent has to be larger */
  width: calc(100% / 1.414);
  border-top: 2px solid #c7c7c7;
  border-left: 2px solid #c7c7c7;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

/* Just for demo */
.arrow { transition: all 1s; }
.arrow:hover { height: 50px; width: 50px; }
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

---

**Using SVG:**

You could also have a look at using SVG for creating such shapes because it is much more easier to do so and the output is also responsive. All we need is one `path` element which creates the shape by connecting the coordinates provided within the `d` attribute. The `M` command moves the pen to the specified coordinate whereas the `L` command draws line from the previous point to the one specified after the command.

```css
svg {
  width: 25px;
  height: 18px;
}
path {
  stroke: #c7c7c7;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: transparent;
}

/* Just for demo */
svg{ transition: all 1s; }
svg:hover{ width: 50px; height: 36px; }
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 50 50' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
  <path id='arrowhead' d='M0,48 L25,2 50,48z' vector-effect='non-scaling-stroke'/>
</svg>
```

---

**Using Gradients:**

The below approach using `linear-gradient` which would also work and would require only a single element but it has lesser browser support and is **suited only for fixed size containers**. Because the gradients use percentage values, **bottom border tends to get thicker as container's dimensions change** (thus rendering it **useless for responsive designs**).

```css
.arrow {
  position: relative;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  border-top: 2px solid #c7c7c7;
  border-left: 2px solid #c7c7c7;
  background: linear-gradient(to left top, transparent 50%, #c7c7c7 50%, #c7c7c7 60%, transparent 60%);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

/* Just for demo */
.arrow { transition: all 1s; }
.arrow:hover { height: 50px; width: 50px; }
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

Comment: Hey I think with your latest edit. The bottom-border has some weird stuff going on. It gets thicker on hover and looks aliased.

Comment: That is correct @CarlEdwards That is what I wanted to illustrate, the last one should not be used for anything other than fixed width shapes. The first two are the best :) Hope you find one of those two helpful.

Comment: Oh that's my bad. I scrolled down too fast without noticing the first solution from yesterday was still there. Sorry for the delay as well. Got caught up with some stuff yesterday that prevented me from looking at the answer in full detail. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @CarlEdwards: That's not a problem. I am glad that I could be of some help :)